How does a miner create multiple outputs in a coinbase transaction?
Bitcoin Core hard-codes the coinbase transaction to one output coinbaseTx.vout.resize(1) as defined in src/node/miner.cpp
     // Create coinbase transaction.
    CMutableTransaction coinbaseTx;
    coinbaseTx.vin.resize(1);
    coinbaseTx.vin[0].prevout.SetNull();

****************************************************
//Referring to the line of code below 
    coinbaseTx.vout.resize(1);

*****************************************************
    coinbaseTx.vout[0].scriptPubKey = scriptPubKeyIn;
    coinbaseTx.vout[0].nValue = nFees + GetBlockSubsidy(nHeight, chainparams.GetConsensus());
    coinbaseTx.vin[0].scriptSig = CScript() << nHeight << OP_0;
    pblock->vtx[0] = MakeTransactionRef(std::move(coinbaseTx));
    pblocktemplate->vchCoinbaseCommitment = m_chainstate.m_chainman.GenerateCoinbaseCommitment(*pblock, pindexPrev);
    pblocktemplate->vTxFees[0] = -nFees;

    LogPrintf("CreateNewBlock(): block weight: %u txs: %u fees: %ld sigops %d\n", GetBlockWeight(*pblock), nBlockTx, nFees, nBlockSigOpsCost);

However, recently in block 860062 the mining pool paid multiple remote miners directly from the coinbase transaction.
How does the miner create a coinbase transaction that overrides the default values stipulated in the above code-snippet from Bitcoin Core?

Bitcoin Core provides two distinct mining interfaces:

A production mining interface through the getblocktemplate RPC, which provides information about the block header and transactions to include, but lets the miner/pool construct the block and coinbase transaction themselves, plus let the miner do their own nonce grinding (the vast majority of the computational work) using specialized hardware/software.
A testing interface through RPCs like generatetoaddress, which construct a full block, grind the nonce using unoptimized CPU code, and submit a block to the network. It's only feasible for test networks where the difficulty is low.

The code you are citing is technically invoked in both interfaces, but for the production one, the resulting coinbase transaction is a dummy that gets ignored; for real-world mining, the coinbase transaction construction is done by the miner's/pool's software or hardware.

Thank you so much for the response. That clears the doubt I had.
